# Sometime Disconnect Req is inside Publish Message

Tags: c++, select, mqtt

On the client side I use:

```
mosquitto_pub -t tpc -m msg
```

On the server side I use nonblocking socket and `socket()` API:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzab6/xnonblock.htm

After first received packet I send **connect acknowledge** packet.

For each received packet I print *how many bytes was received* and *whole buffer* in hex.

I compare received data with WireShark capturing.

Sometime it works well:

```
37 bytes received - Connect Command
10 bytes received - Publish Message [tpc]
2 bytes received - Disconnect Req
```

Sometime I get **Disconnect Req** inside **Publish Message [tpc]**:

```
37 bytes received - Connect Command
12 bytes received - Publish Message [tpc] + Disconnect Req
```

These last two bytes are **Disconnect Req**:

```
30
8
0
3
74
70
63
6d
73
67
ffffffe0  <--
0         <--
```

How can I avoid these situations and get always 3 packets?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't. You have to actually parse the messages to determine the length.

The constant to create a tcp socket is called `SOCK_STREAM` for a reason. Socket has to be treated as such: a stream of bytes. Nobody guarantees that one `send()` on one side results in one `recv()` on the other side. The only guarantee is that the sequence is preserved: `abcd` may become (`ab`, `cd`), but will not become `acbd`.
The packets may be splitted somewhere half the way. So it may be that the client sends 2048 bytes, but on the server side you'll receive first ~1400 bytes and then the rest. So N `send`s does not result in N `recv`.

Another thing is that the client also treats the socket as a stream. It may send byte by byte, or send a batch of messages with one `send()`. `N` messages are not N `send`s.